# Test If A Foreach is Successful

Tags: php

I need a way to detect if the '**foreach**' is *unsuccessful*. If it is *unsuccessful*, then *repeat the same error message* that is in the current '**else**'.

```
<?php

    if(file_exists('redirects.xml')) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('redirects.xml');
        if(isset($_GET['r']) && $_GET['r'] != '' && !is_array($_GET['r'])) {
            foreach($xml->short as $shorts) {
                if($shorts->name == $_GET['r']) {
                    header('Location: '.$shorts->url);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            header("refresh:2;url=http://www.wlatw.co/");
            echo '<div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 24px;">Malformed URL</div><div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 16px;">Redirecting...</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What makes the `foreach` loop successful or unsuccessful? Do you mean if there are no `$xml->short` to iterate as a non-success?

Comment: You should always terminate the script after `header('Location:...')` headers. Use `die;` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a variable to keep track of the loop's status.

```
<?php

if(file_exists('redirects.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('redirects.xml');
    if(isset($_GET['r']) && $_GET['r'] != '' && !is_array($_GET['r'])) {
        $url_is_malformed = false;
        foreach($xml->short as $shorts) {
            if($shorts->name == $_GET['r']) {
                header('Location: '.$shorts->url);
                break;
            }
        }
        $url_is_malformed = true;
    }
    else {
        $file_doesnt_exist = true;
    }

    if( $file_doesnt_exist || $url_is_malformed )
    {
        header("refresh:2;url=http://www.wlatw.co/");
        echo '<div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 24px;">Malformed URL</div><div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 16px;">Redirecting...</div>';
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 3):

Create a flag before starting the loop;
Set it to unsuccesful when it fails.

```
<?php

    if(file_exists('redirects.xml')) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('redirects.xml');
        if(isset($_GET['r']) && $_GET['r'] != '' && !is_array($_GET['r'])) {
            $success = false; // set the flag
            foreach($xml->short as $shorts) {
                if($shorts->name == $_GET['r']) {
                    header('Location: '.$shorts->url);
                    $success = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ($success) { // do what you want when not success ful.
                header("refresh:2;url=http://www.wlatw.co/");
                echo '<div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 24px;">Malformed URL</div><div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 16px;">Redirecting...</div>';
            }
        }
        else {
            header("refresh:2;url=http://www.wlatw.co/");
            echo '<div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 24px;">Malformed URL</div><div align="center" style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 16px;">Redirecting...</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

But looking at your code, you can just exit after setting the header:

```
foreach($xml->short as $shorts) {
    if($shorts->name == $_GET['r']) {
        header('Location: '.$shorts->url);
        exit;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Note:** As @Sverri M. Olsen said, you should always stop your script after setting the Location header, either with die, exit or any other mechanism you have.

Comment: I was going to comment on the exit's but if the code is changed later not to have redirects there, the flags would be the best solution.